# Replacement not working with overlay configmap values

Tags: kustomize

I'm trying to replace the configMapGenerator env values by creating an overlay.
The expected overlay values show up in the configmap, but not in the ExternalSecret trough the replacements.
I have the following base/kustomization.yaml where I'm doing some replacements:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- ex-secret.yaml

configMapGenerator:
- name: test
  envs:
    - env.properties

replacements:
- source:
    name: test
    kind: ConfigMap
    fieldPath: data.KEY
  targets:
    - select:
        kind: ExternalSecret
        name: prime-manager
      fieldPaths:
        - "spec.data.[secretKey=PRIME_MANAGER_CONSOLE_DB_password].remoteRef.key"
- source:
    name: test
    kind: ConfigMap
    fieldPath: data.KEY2
  targets:
    - select:
        kind: ExternalSecret
        name: prime-manager
      fieldPaths:
        - "spec.data.[secretKey=PRIME_MANAGER_WEB_DB_password].remoteRef.key"
- source:
    name: test
    kind: ConfigMap
    fieldPath: data.KEY3
  targets:
    - select:
        kind: ExternalSecret
        name: prime-manager
      fieldPaths:
        - "spec.data.[secretKey=PRIME_MANAGER_PARAMS_admin_password].remoteRef.key"
```

The base/env.properties file in the base contains the following properties and values:

```
KEY=test
KEY2=test2
KEY3=test3
```

base/ex-secret.yaml file for reproduce:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: prime-manager
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prime-manager
spec:
  refreshInterval: 1h
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
    name: keyvault-secret-store

  data:
  - secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_CONSOLE_DB_password
    remoteRef:
      key: prime-manager-console-postgres-password-staging
  - secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_WEB_DB_password
    remoteRef:
      key: prime-manager-web-postgres-password-staging
  - secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_PARAMS_admin_password
    remoteRef:
      key: prime-manager-ferrontest-admin-password-staging
```

Now I have created an overlay overlay/kustomization.yaml to overwrite the values like

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- ../base

configMapGenerator:
- name: test
  behavior: replace
  envs:
    - env.properties
```

overlay/env.properties:

```
KEY=testen
KEY2=testen2
KEY3=testen3
```

File tree:

```
C:.
├───base
│       env.properties
│       ex-secret.yaml
│       kustomization.yaml
│
└───overlay
        env.properties
        kustomization.yaml
```

**Expected output**

I would expect testen, testen2 and testen3 to show up in the ExternalSecret output.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  KEY: testen
  KEY2: testen2
  KEY3: testen3
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-hbtgc5f7dm
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prime-manager
  name: prime-manager
spec:
  data:
  - remoteRef:
      key: testen
    secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_CONSOLE_DB_password
  - remoteRef:
      key: testen2
    secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_WEB_DB_password
  - remoteRef:
      key: testen3
    secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_PARAMS_admin_password
  refreshInterval: 1h
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
    name: keyvault-secret-store
```

**Actual output**

But I'm still getting the base values in the ExternalSecret output.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  KEY: testen
  KEY2: testen2
  KEY3: testen3
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-hbtgc5f7dm
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prime-manager
  name: prime-manager
spec:
  data:
  - remoteRef:
      key: test
    secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_CONSOLE_DB_password
  - remoteRef:
      key: test2
    secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_WEB_DB_password
  - remoteRef:
      key: test3
    secretKey: PRIME_MANAGER_PARAMS_admin_password
  refreshInterval: 1h
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
    name: keyvault-secret-store
```

**Kustomize version**

v4.5.7

**Platform**

Windows

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4795). Essentially, for the `replacements` to work with the overlay's updated secrets, they must be run from the overlay's kustomization.yaml file instead of the base.

If one moves the `replacements` code to a separate file, the updated "overlay/kustomization.yaml" could look like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../base

configMapGenerator:
- name: test
  behavior: replace
  envs:
    - env.properties

replacements:
  - path: ../base/replacements.yaml
```